# Query to Select Latest Employee Entry Per Each Hour

Tags: sql

How would I modify the following SQL query code to return the latest entry of each employee per hour, instead of currently returning every occurrence from each employee regardless of how many times it appears in the query per each hour.

For example, if an employee has 4 entries between 2-3 PM and 1 entry between 3-4 PM, only returning the last entry in the 2-3 PM interval and the 1 entry in the 3-4 PM interval.

SQL Query Code:

```
SELECT
     EMPLOYEE_ID
     FIRST_NAME
     LAST_NAME
     MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS LATEST_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
     MAIN.DATABASE
GROUP BY
     EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP desc;
```

Data Table:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | John | Doe | 8/17/2021 3:39:39.000000 PM |
| 123456789 | John | Doe | 7/23/2021 2:13:55.000000 PM |
| 123456789 | John | Doe | 7/23/2021 2:13:54.000000 PM |
| 123456789 | John | Doe | 7/23/2021 2:13:53.000000 PM |
| 123456789 | John | Doe | 7/23/2021 2:13:52.000000 PM |

Comment: Your title says "Oracle" and your tags say [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysql]]... What are you *really* using. Fix your tags please.

Comment: Also, aggregating and grouping on the same column rarely is the right choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle -- as the title suggests -- then you can use `row_number()` like this:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id, trunc(timestamp, 'HH') order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from main.database d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Awesome - this works. I just needed to add another "order by timestamp desc" at the end in order to get all of the remaining entries in order of most recent to oldest.